# .NET Core 3.1 Web API Bearer Token ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Firstly, apologies if this is worded poorly or missing any information to start with, I am very new to web authentication!

So I have a created a Blazor application that uses the ASP.NET Identity model to Register/Login users, stored in a SQL Server database. This all works perfectly!

Now what I want to do is create an .NET Core 3.1 Web API project that uses the same database for user management. This API should be secured by a token which will be obtained by posting the username and password to the /token endpoint of the API. This token is then used in subsequent API calls.

I have been searching and following tutorials on these for days now and all seem to be around .NET Core 2.0 and try the below. But this is not working, does anyone have a tutorial for .NET Core 3.1 or can advise to achieve this.

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

This is designed for IAppBuilder but the newer versions use IApplicationBuilder which appears quite different. Also these tutorials do not show how to link to the ASP.NET Identity database.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to overcomplicate it with an oauth server. Sign the tokens yourself with [`JwtSecurityTokenHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=azure-dotnet). Then add an authentication handler `services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(...)` to verify the token

Comment: I can provide a more in-depth answer if you need pointers